# Importance of active_ids and active_id in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

What are the key roles of **active_ids** and **active_id** in development ?
I want to know **Advantages** and **Limitations** of that functionality provided by odoo.

In certain case what we can do if I can not get the active_ids in context while opening wizard from other model's list view ?

Here is the action which I used to open my wizard from list view of **product.product** model.

```
<act_window name="Calculate Product Price" 
            res_model="wizard.main"
            src_model="product.product" 
            view_mode="form" 
            view_type="form"
            target="current" 
            multi="True" 
            key2="client_action_multi"
            id="action_product_price_calculator_ept"
            view_id="view_product_calculator_wizard"/>
```

Here is my python code to get active ids.

```
@api.model
def default_get(self, fields):
    context = self.env.context
    res = super(wizard_main, self).default_get(fields)
    product_ids = context.get('active_ids',[])
    if not product_ids:
        return res
    #### few more lines will be added here 
    return res
```